# VM Metrics - Azure - How to check cpu & memory utilization by a single process?

Tags: linux, azure, centos, azure-monitoring

I was just trying to monitor a **Linux VM** and sudden spike in metrics was there.
Still, for basic troubleshoot I had to login into the machine and run `top` (which couldn't really tell me the past usage) to see which process is eating up the resources.

Is there any way to query (log analytics) or apply any metrics so that i could see all the processes that are running in my VM with their CPU & Memory Utilization.

If not in Azure, would love some help if someone could suggest some tool/agent that i can configure in the machine.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible by querying Perf table as described here:
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-observability/creat-a-query-to-get-cpu-usage-from-every-process-on-the-vm/m-p/3262559

It should contain data from Windows and Linux VMs as described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/reference/tables/perf

You need to configure your agent in Log Analytics Workspace instance first to collect counters you need by default process information is not collected. You may set collection of data in **Agent Configuration** pane Under **Settings** tab:

[image]

Once you got this configured you'll find Perf tabel and data collected in **Logs** under **LogManagement**. It takes few minutes for data to show in this table.

[image]

Comment: thanks for replying, but i can't even see anything when i type only type Pref (Whole query isn't producing any output at all) in logs, any solution for that?

"No Result Found" is written.

Comment: Updated my answer to include information how to get Performance counters.

Comment: thanks, added them yesterday.
perf showing entries now.

Comment: Can you please help on what is **Pct Privileged Time** & **Pct User Time**.

Comment: **Pct Privileged Time**  is percentage of the CPU time when process executes is in Kernel mode 

**Pct User Time** is percentage of the CPU time process executes non kernel tasks

It is well explained here: https://scoutapm.com/blog/understanding-linuxs-cpu-stats

Comment: Hi Greg, Could you also help me in one more thing. Now i can see the services perfectly, but in that specific service  if i want to set an alert on a specific service so that i can be informed if that service is down for 30seconds. Is it possible from Log Analytics Workspace?

Comment: @techworm, if you can query it in LAW than you can set alarm. please check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-log for details

Comment: thanks again @Greg, exactly what's needed.